# Flexslider changes position after tab switch

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

I'am using this flexslider: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

If i take a look at the generated/modified HTML:

```
...
<ul class="slides" style="width: 7800%; -webkit-transition: 0.6s; transition: 0.6s; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1274px, 0px, 0px);">
...
```

It works fine but if i change and switch back to the tab or close the network panel the HTML is modified again:

```
...
<ul class="slides" style="width: 7800%; -webkit-transition: 0s; transition: 0s; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1855px, 0px, 0px);">
...
```

As you can see the first parameter of translate3d() has been changed, which couses ofcourse a styling issue.

Any ideas why flexslider is doing this?
No, its not becouse looping threw the items becouse i set the option, which is working:

> animationLoop: false

Comment: It must be something else that adds that as I've never seen flexslider add transition or transform css before